# Failed to resolve: com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.4.1

Tags: android-studio

When I integrate PayU payment gateway with my mobile app, the below error is throwing in gradle build:

> Failed to resolve: com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.4.1

My `build.gradile` file looks like this

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.4.1'`enter code here`
    compile 'com.payu.magicretry:magicretry:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:6.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile files('lib/payu-sdk-4.3.1-sources.jar')
}
```

Kindly help

Comment: Remove, `enter code here`

Comment: Looks like your Android Studio is in offline mode. Disable offline mode and re-sync project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your integrations and add this line :

```
compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.4.4'
```